# Drag n drop in swt/eclipse tree viewer

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt

I have applied drag and drop option in SWT tree viewer and it is working quite fine but i want to allow DND to only a particular sub tree type. I did it by suitable check. Now the problem is that those tree node on which i have not applied DND is draggable though they could not be dropped due to my check.
 I want to stop them for being draggable too.

Please suggest what could be the problem which i am not able to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the method:

```
public void org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSourceAdapter.dragStart(final DragSourceEvent event) {
 if (... some condition) {
    event.doit = false; // this will cancel DnD operation
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out my fault...ya thats what i was not doing..thanks again